# Angularjs input[radio] with unique ng-model not unsetting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, radio-button

Simple issue, when using a collection of radio-buttons, each using a unique `ng-model`, when one is **un-selected**, the value for the model does not change from `true` to `false`.

In this example, when unselected, each model still retains 'true':

```
<form>
    <label for='qpInputdata'>No Selection</label>
    <input id="qpInputdata" class="form-control
       name="xCaasType" ng-model="fData.xNone" type="radio"
       ng-value="true" value="true">
    <label for='qpInputdata'>Select This One</label>
    <input id="qpInputdata" class="form-control
        name="xCaasType" ng-model="fData.xNotNone" type="radio"
        ng-value="true" value="true">
</form>
```

As always, thanks for your guidance.

Comment: radio buttons should use the same `ng-model` unless its a different radio button group and in that case, you use a different model.

Comment: if it shares a name it should share the model...that's how radios work. Doesn't make sense having different model. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is part of a dynamic form tool. I need to accommodate different data types. This specific example should set a 'true' for the item selected and 'false' otherwise. These models are then used to take input and to save/retrieve data from a db.

Comment: One additional item, I tried the suggested settings ng-true-value and ng-false-value to no success.  It seems to break the binding to the scope.

Answer (score -1):

your form should be something like this

```
<form>
    <label for='qpInputdata'>No Selection</label>
    <input id="qpInputdata" class="form-control
       name="xCaasType" ng-model="fData.selection" type="radio"
       ng-value="true" value="no">
    <label for='qpInputdata'>Select This One</label>
    <input id="qpInputdata" class="form-control
        name="xCaasType" ng-model="fData.selection" type="radio"
        ng-value="true" value="selected">
</form>
```

now the model **fData.selection** will hold one of these two values "no","selected" according to the selected option